# VueJS Get ID's of checked boxes in an array

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to

1. build a set of checkboxes from an array (of database data returned from an API call)
2. default the checkboxes to "checked"
3. retrieve the database ID values of the checked boxes after the user has adjusted them

I can accomplish #1 and #3 by doing a non-standard mix of v-bind and v-model.  But nothing I've tried will also accomplish #2.  My checkboxes stubbornly default to un-checked.

My template is

```
<div v-for="manager in managers">
     <input type="checkbox"  
            v-bind:id="'manager-'+manager.relationship_id" 
            v-bind:name="'manager-'+manager.relationship_id" 
            v-bind:value="manager.relationship_id" 
            v-bind:checked="manager.isChecked"
            v-model="selected.manager_ids"
      />
      <label v-bind:for="'manager-'+manager.relationship_id">{{ manager.first_name }} {{ manager.last_name }}</label>
</div>
```

I retrieve the managers from the database and then add an isChecked attribute via this function:

```
getManagers: function (){
   // API for managers
   let url = (my api url) ;
   fetch(url).then((response) => {
       return response.json()
       }).then((data) => {
          this.managers = data;
          this.managers.map(manager => {
             manager['isChecked'] = true;
             return manager;
          })
      });
},
```

I want to use the checked ID's here (just a console log for now, will be real code later):

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.selected.manager_ids.length; i++) {
    console.log(this.selected.manager_ids[i])
}
```

I think I need the **v-bind:value="manager.relationship_id"** so that the database ID becomes the value.  And I think I need the **v-model="selected.manager_ids"** so that the checked results go into a separate array and don't try to update the database array.

The boxes load fine from managers, and the selected.manager_ids array ends up with what I want: the database ID's of only the checked managers.  All I need is for the isChecked default to work.  I've spent several hours just on that.

Why isn't the **v-bind:checked="manager.isChecked"** taking effect?  Or is there a completely different way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the "isChecked" prop to each item of the array, and if you want all the checkboxes to be checked. Just let the `manager_ids` array receive the array fetched from the database and v-model will do the rest

```js
fetch(url).then((response) => {
   return response.json()
   }).then((data) => {
     this.managers = data;
     this.selected.manager_ids =  this.managers.map(manager => manager.relationship_id);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Your labels dont need `for` and your inputs dont need `id` when wrapped around the label element.

Second, if you set the value to the manager ID this will use it as the value on v-model.

```
<template>
  <div class="flex h-screen items-center justify-center">
    <div v-for="manager in managers" :key="manager.id">
      <label>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected.manager_ids" :value="manager.id">
          {{ manager.first_name }} {{ manager.last_name }}
      </label>
    </div>
    {{ selected.manager_ids }}
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selected: {
        manager_ids: [3],
      },
      managers: [
        {id: 1, first_name: "John", last_name: "smith" },
        {id: 2, first_name: "John", last_name: "smith" },
        {id: 3, first_name: "John", last_name: "smith" },
        {id: 4, first_name: "John", last_name: "smith" },
        {id: 5, first_name: "John", last_name: "smith" },
      ],
    };
  },
}
</script>
```

If you want them to default to checked, You can do a map after you get them.

```
getManagers: function (){
   let url = (my api url) ;
   fetch(url).then((response) => {
       return response.json()
       }).then((data) => {
          this.managers = data;
          this.selected.manager_ids = data.map(manager => {
            return manager.id;
          })
      });
```